# Hide/Show menu with increase/decrease of width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following. Its working fine, but I want to increase the size of .table when the .sidebarmenu is hidden.  How can I do this??  [THIS IS WHAT I HAVE](http://jsfiddle.net/Anusha_Mallajosyula/a2v5J/3/)

HTML:

```
<button id="showmenu" type="button">Hide menu</button>
<div class="sidebarmenu">
    This should go left
</div>
<div class="table">
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showmenu').click(function () {
        var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');
        $('#showmenu').text(hidden ? 'Hide Menu' : 'Show Menu');
        if (hidden) {
            $('.sidebarmenu').animate({
                left: '0px'
            }, 500)
        } else {
            $('.sidebarmenu').animate({
                left: '-200px'
            }, 500)
        }
        $('.sidebarmenu,.image').data("hidden", !hidden);

    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.sidebarmenu {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
    width:200px;
    background:red;
    left:0px;
}
.table {
    height:500px;
    width:300px;
    background:pink;
    float:left;
    left:20px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you want?

Comment: If you are seeing the fiddle, I want the div in pink to occupy the white space on left when the red div is hiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code in order to do what you wanted. http://jsfiddle.net/a2v5J/28/

**HTML**

```
     <button id="showmenu" type="button">Hide menu</button>

     <div id="sidemenu" class="sidemenu"> <!-- This is the container that resize-->
       <div id="innermenu" class="innermenu"> <!--This is the container to keep the width of the menucontent-->

         <!-- Here you can put whatever you want-->
         <div class="sidebarmenu">
               This should go left
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="table">
         content
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  /* This is following your old structure but adds a overflow to hide the menu content when width is 0 */
  .sidemenu { 
        float:left;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 200px;
        height: 500px;
      }

  /*this must have the desired width, it is going to be hidden by the overflow of the parent*/
  .innermenu {    
        height: 100%;
        width: 200px;
        background: #bcc1cb;
      }

  /*Just added the height to show it more beautiful*/
  .sidebarmenu {
      height: 100%;
  }

  .table{
      height:500px;
      width:300px;
      background:pink;
      float:left;
      left:20px;
      z-index: 10;
  }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#showmenu').click(function() {
      var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');
      $('#showmenu').text(hidden ? 'Hide Menu' : 'Show Menu');
          if(hidden){
          /* One gets smaller and one gets bigger*/
          $('.sidemenu').animate({
              width: '200px'
          },500);
          $('.table').animate({
              width: '300px'
          },500)
      } else {
          $('.sidemenu').animate({
              width: '0px'
          },500);
           $('.table').animate({
              width: '500px'
          },500)
      }
      $('.sidebarmenu,.image').data("hidden", !hidden);

      });
  });
```

Don't use positioning or margin but use width.
I had to add two div around your menu.
One is needed to keep the content of the menu with a fixed width (so it doesn't resize while you change the container dimension), and the outer div is for resizing the menu and has overflow hidden to hide the innermenu

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to change a bit your HTMl markup as well as your CSS.
Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/a2v5J/5/

I added a `wrap` and changed the position of the menu to `absolute` adding also a `padding` of 200px to the `table` element.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="sidebarmenu">This should go left</div>
    <div class="table"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.sidebarmenu {
    position:absolute; /*added*/
    float:left;
    height:500px;
    width:200px;
    background:red;
    left:0px;  /*added*/
    top:0;/*added*/
}

.table {
    height:500px;
    width:300px;
    background:pink;
    float:left;
    padding-left:200px;   /*added*/
}
```

## UPDATE

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a2v5J/18/

I added two animations for the `.table` element in order to change its `width` and `padding` properties.

```
$('.table').animate({
     paddingLeft: '0px',
      width: '500px'
}, 500);

//.....

$('.table').animate({
     paddingLeft: '200px',
     width: '300px'
}, 500);
```

Comment: I want it this really working to be displayed to the left corner when the red div hides. http://jsfiddle.net/a2v5J/8/

Answer (score 0):

Check [this updated right box alignment](http://jsfiddle.net/a2v5J/119/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
    var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');
    $('#showmenu').text(hidden ? 'Hide Menu' : 'Show Menu');
    if(hidden){
        $('.sidebarmenu').animate({
            left: '0px'
        },500)
         $('.table').animate({
            left: '20px'
        },500)
    } else {
        $('.sidebarmenu').animate({
            left: '-200px'
        },500)
        $('.table').animate({`enter code here`
            left: '-200px'
        },500)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Added animation to the `.table` also. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2v5J/11/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
    var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');
    $('#showmenu').text(hidden ? 'Hide Menu' : 'Show Menu');
    if(hidden){
        $('.sidebarmenu').animate({
            left: '0px'
        },500)
         $('.table').animate({
            left: '0px'
        },500)
    } else {
        $('.sidebarmenu').animate({
            left: '-200px'
        },500)
        $('.table').animate({
            left: '-200px'
        },500)
    }
    $('.sidebarmenu,.image').data("hidden", !hidden);

    });
});
```

### Update

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a2v5J/30/) (updated again)

You can add more options to the animate method

```
$('.table').animate({
            left: '-200px',
            width: '350px'
        },500)
```

Comment: he he... it just goes down because there is no wrapper for these 2 divs.